# how to get a list of sorted values filling missing ones in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

given a list of goods:
`goodlist = ['bread', 'water', 'salt', 'saffron', 'mustard']`
and given a pandas dataframe with values for *some* of the goods:
`new_qty = pd.DataFrame(zip(['water', 'saffron'], [42, 1.5]), columns = [ 'good', 'qty'])`
I would like to return an array holding the quantity for *all* goods:
`expected = [ 0.0, 42.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0 ]`

The function consuming this data is aware of goodlist, so the order *must* be correct.

I can solve the problem with a for loop but I'm quite sure python has better tools to do that, ideally something from numpy or tensorflow... This code is going to be called a lot, so speed also does matter.

If someone could please suggest a solution within this constraints?

Comment: can you share your code what you actually tried so far

Comment: I don't see the point really, as I said, i can solve it with a for loop which is not what I want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
l = new_qty.set_index('good')['qty'].reindex(goodlist,fill_value=0).tolist()
Out[700]: [0.0, 42.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0]
```